# chrome extension processes onCreate osProcessId mismatch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have hooked into chrome.processes.onCreated and chrome.processes.onExited.

```
chrome.processes.onCreated.addListener(this.processesOnCreated.bind(this));
chrome.processes.onExited.addListener(this.processesOnExited.bind(this));
```

My goal is to get the osProcessId whenever a tab is created and communicate it the a native app so that can do its job based on the OS Pid of the process.
Here is a snipped of the chrome.processes.onCreated code:

```
processesOnCreated: function(process)
{
    var osPID = process.osProcessId;
    var processType = process.type;

  },
```

Initially when I create a new tab, I can see the processesOnCreated being fired and I can see the process with process.osProcessId in the windows task manager as well where process.osProcessID = Windows Process ID (PID). 
If I type in a new url in the address bar (of the current tab) and load the page, a new process gets created and the previous process is terminated. I can see in Windows Task manager that the osProcessId that I tracked using processOnCreated is not available anymore and is instead replaced with a new chrome process.

Here is where I am having trouble:
There is no processes.onExited being fired for the process that got terminated. Also, in the processes.onCreated being fired for the new process that renders the page, the osProcessId in the callback (process object) has the pid of the previous process (currently being terminated by chrome) and not the pid for the new process. I can see the change in the windows task manager though.

Consequently, my native app tries to load details of a process that doesn't exist any more and this causes issues.